# As I can send data from one form to another from jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, serialization

I have the following problem. I have two forms and need the second bailout form the first data

Example :

```
//Form 1
<form id="form1">
      <input type="text" name="years">
</form>

//Form 2
<form id="form2">
      <input type="text" name="month">
      <input onclick="sendForm()">
</form>

<script>
       function sendForm(){
          // I need get data from first and second form 
          $("#form2").submit();
       }
</script>
```

I tried to serialize( ) function

Example:

```
 //Form 1
<form id="form1">
      <input type="text" name="years">
</form>

//Form 2
<form id="form2">
      <input type="hidden" name="dataForm1" id="dataForm1">
      <input type="text" name="month">
      <input onclick="sendForm()">
</form>

<script>
       function sendForm(){
          // I need get data from first and second form 
          $("#dataForm1").val($("#form1").serialize())
          $("#form2").submit();
       }
</script>
```

but it does not work when there spaces

Please Help !! I search a solutions for much time
Thanks !!!!

Comment: Never use `click` events for `submit` as they forget you can submit using keyboard. Use the `submit` event instead.Also calling val() on a form does nothing useful that I know of. You need to copy the inputs from one form to the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new form and add elements from the two other forms and submit the new one. This will also be invisible to the user.

This example takes the src from form2, but your example does not have one. Adapt the function if you need it from somewhere else. The new form will have all input elements created as hidden but it could just as well be text.

I hope this helps or at least inspire you to a better solution.

```
function sendForm()
{
    var newForm = $("<form>", {"src":$("#form2").attr("src")});
    $("form").children().each(function(key, value)
    {
        var inputElement = $(value);
        var newHidden = $("<input>", {type:"hidden", "name": inputElement.attr("name"), "value": inputElement.val()});
        newForm.append(newHidden);
    });
    newForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: Feel free to accept and/or up vote my answer if it solved your problem. :)